# Не понимаю как использовать концепцию Событийно-Ориентированного Программирования в C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Есть некий метод Attack(). В нем реализована анимация для Unity (Если нажимаешь левую кнопку мыши, то идет анимация атаки). Как можно сделать через delegate и event, чтобы метод обрабатывался только когда нажимаешь кнопку, а не каждый кадр через, как в Update()?

```
public void Attack()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Attack");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ответ: Никак, с точки зрения ООП лучше в Update перенеси проверку клика мыши, а при клике (в if) – вызвать метод attack, где проигрывается анимация. Если тебе нужен клик по спрайту или кнопки, ТОЛЬКО в этом случае можно вызвать метод OnPointerClick [подробнее про обработки события клика на спрайт](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1095047/detect-mouse-events-for-ui-canvas.html)

Comment: Они же как-то сделали с помощью делегатов OnPointerClick. Почему тогда это никак не сделать?

Comment: Делегат - это всего лишь метод, который выполнится. Его нужно повесить на какое-то событие. События обычно принадлежат объектам. А вы будете кликать в пустоту, как вы хотите обработать данные действия?

Comment: Ок, теперь понял, а при нажатии клавиш на клавиатуре, они тоже будут нажиматься по пустоте?

Comment: А почему у тебя такая тяга к событейно-ориентированному? Такой подход не всегда хорош: и производительность страдает и проект становится более запутанным. Если у тебя БОЛЬШОЙ проект где много объектов, тогда можно сделать класс, например, GameManager, который проверяет клик мышки и/или нажатия клавиш и кастит события, а все кому интересно (игрок например) подписываются на это событие и, в твоем случае, это будет метод attack, тогда это событейно-ориентированно.

Comment: В книге Алан Торн утверждает обратное. Хотел проверить что лучше.

Comment: Выбор за тобой, делай как считаешь нужным. Главное чтобы работало :)